# Commenting out a table row

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

Is it possible to comment out a table row in (github-flavoured) markdown?

```
|   ID    |              Info               |
| ------- | ------------------------------- |
| 1       | I want to keep this row         |
| 2       | This row must be commented out! |
| 3       | I want to keep this row         |
```

It doesn't seem to work with HTML comments, the rows beneath the commented row will not be recognized as table rows anymore. ([example gist](https://gist.github.com/hypothermic/14a6ac6dab7678b0706db390f3050451))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to comment out a table row in (github-flavoured) Markdown. In fact the [spec](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-) explicitly states:

> The table is broken at the first empty line, or beginning of another block-level structure

Of course, an HTML comment is "another block-level structure." Therefore, the comment ends the table. At best, any addition table rows would be seen as a separate table. However, as they do not have a header attached to them, they do not constitute a complete table and therefore are not seen as rows.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the line break before the line you want to remove.

```
|   ID    |              Info               |
| ------- | ------------------------------- |
| 1       | I want to keep this row         |<!--| 2       | This row must be commented out! |-->
| 3       | I want to keep this row         |
```